# What is the criteria that determines the difference between a plate and membrane, with material considerations?

Tags: acoustics, material-science

So according to Venstel and Frauthammer in their 2001 book, the criteria for differentiating between rigid plates, thin plates and membranes is $a/h$ where a is a typical in-plane dimension (the length of a square plate), and h is the height.

$a/h < 8$ corresponds to a rigid plate

$8 < a/h < 80$ is a thin plate

$a/h > 80$ is a membrane

However, using this criteria, I have a square plate of Aluminum Nitride, which is $L=15cm$ on a side and $h=0.04cm$. By their criteria, this should be well within the membrane region ($a/h = 375$) with zero flexural rigidity, however, that is not the case at all. It clearly behaves like a thin plate and does have noticeble flexural rigidity.

where flexural rigidity is $D = Eh^3/12(1- v^2)$

E being youngs modulus and $v$ being Poisson's ratio.

My question is this: is there another criteria that includes something like flexural rigidity or young's modulus which differentiates between a plate and membrane?

Comment: I don't know why you tagged the "acoustics" and I don't have the book, but *taken out of context* the criteria you quoted look like nonsense to me. There is no way a 1 m square steel plate 1 cm thick (a/h = 100) is going to behave like a "membrane" for example. Even 1 mm thick (a/h = 1000) might be marginal. And it doesn't make any sense to jump from "rigid" to "thin" plates without a category of "thick" (but not rigid) plates in between.

Comment: I tagged it as acoustics as this is in the context of acoustics. However, I am just quoting the criteria which was presented by Venstel, which from my research seems to be accepted and cited by others. You can find the book here: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/98b6/b666a3ae163c8d6d53ac66a39966dbe38ce0.pdf (page 15 of the pdf).

Comment: Also, I agree that the criteria doesn't work, unless I am misunderstanding something, which is why I asked.

Comment: I don't have time to read the book to form an opinion on it, but if you want a *reliable* source of information, read this: https://archive.org/details/TheoryOfPlatesAndShells. Yes it is now 60 years old, but unless you are doing something very exotic, that is totally irrelevant.

Comment: "... which from my research seems to be accepted and cited by others." I'm reminded of a keynote paper at a mech eng conference back in the 1970s, with the title "90% of all computer structural analysis is junk". In fact the author presented it again ten years later, and changed the title: "90%" was replaced by "99%". Or to quote a much older publication, "when one blind man leads another, will not both of them fall into a ditch?"

Comment: You could use the flexural rigidity and mass of the plate to estimate the frequency of some mode with a clamped boundary. If it's an audible frequency then the plate behaves as a membrane (at least for this mode).